# message gets sent before it has required all the data, which means that it sends a couple of messages with the same data in all the messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm learning node js, and want the code to wait to retrieve the data before it sends the message. Right now it seems like it gets some of the data from the page and just goes with it and sends all the messages with the same data. Could someone help me? I would really appreciate it, Thanks in advance.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const path = require("path");
const {
    RichEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const {
    stripIndents
} = require("common-tags");
const {
    cyan
} = require("../../colours.json");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "viewfavoritequotes",
        description: "Shows all your favorite quotes as individual messages.",
        accessableby: "Member",
        category: "miscellaneous",
        aliases: ["viewfavquote", "viewfav", "viewfavq", "vfq"]
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        let arText;
        let enText;
        let surah;
        let ayahNumber;
        let englishName;
        let englishNameTranslation;
        let ayah;
        let number;
        let foundFile;

        const quotes = `././favoritequotes/${message.author.id}/`;
        fs.readdir(quotes, async function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
            }
            files.forEach(async function (file) {
                file = file.substring(0, file.indexOf('_'));
                const url = "https://api.alquran.cloud/ayah/" + file + "/en.asad";
                const urlArabic = "https://api.alquran.cloud/ayah/" + file;
                await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                    enText = data.data.text;
                    await fetch(urlArabic).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                        arText = data.data.text;
                        ayahNumber = data.data.numberInSurah;
                        surah = data.data.surah.number;
                        englishName = data.data.surah.englishName;
                        englishNameTranslation = data.data.surah.englishNameTranslation;
                        number = data.data.number;

                        let embed = new RichEmbed()
                            .addField("Arabic", arText)
                            .addField("English", enText)
                            .setColor(cyan)
                            .setDescription(englishName + " (" + englishNameTranslation + ") " + surah + ":" + ayahNumber + " | Number: " + number)
                            .setAuthor(`Random quran quote!`, message.guild.iconURL)
                        await message.channel.send(embed);
                    })
                });
                setTimeout(function(){console.log("1 second timeout");}, 1500);
            })
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array.prototype.forEach` it`s a callback function, better use `for (cosnt file of files)` for this.

This soltuin must work corretly, and you don`t need use await when use use `.then(data=>)`

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const path = require("path");
const {
    RichEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const {
    stripIndents
} = require("common-tags");
const {
    cyan
} = require("../../colours.json");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "viewfavoritequotes",
        description: "Shows all your favorite quotes as individual messages.",
        accessableby: "Member",
        category: "miscellaneous",
        aliases: ["viewfavquote", "viewfav", "viewfavq", "vfq"]
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        const quotes = `././favoritequotes/${message.author.id}/`;
        fs.readdir(quotes, async function (err, files) {
            if (err) console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
            for ( let file of files) {
                file = file.substring(0, file.indexOf('_'));
                let url = "https://api.alquran.cloud/ayah/" + file + "/en.asad";
                let urlArabic = "https://api.alquran.cloud/ayah/" + file;
                await fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                     let enText = data.data.text;
                     fetch(urlArabic).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                        let arText = data.data.text;
                        let ayahNumber = data.data.numberInSurah;
                        let surah = data.data.surah.number;
                        let englishName = data.data.surah.englishName;
                        let englishNameTranslation = data.data.surah.englishNameTranslation;
                        number = data.data.number;

                        let embed = new RichEmbed()
                            .addField("Arabic", arText)
                            .addField("English", enText)
                            .setColor(cyan)
                            .setDescription(englishName + " (" + englishNameTranslation + ") " + surah + ":" + ayahNumber + " | Number: " + number)
                            .setAuthor(`Random quran quote!`, message.guild.iconURL)
                        await message.channel.send(embed);
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```